# Show partial string in tooltip

Tags: mustache, cartodb

how can I display only the first 5 characters of a field in the tooltip in cartodb? My HTML snippet is:

```
<div class="cartodb-tooltip-content-wrapper">
  <div class="cartodb-tooltip-content">
    <p><b>{{sunset_string}}</b></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This shows the full string (e.g. 22:05:00), but I only want to show 22:05. Ideally, I would change all the values in the database, but is there a way to do this using mustache? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You dont want to change the values in the database. The database should remain the same. You need some sort of ViewModel in your presentation logic that does this for you. Not even Mustache since it is a logic-less template system.

You need then to format this time before you display it in your presentation layer.